# Count and sum up specific decimal number (bash,awk,perl)

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have a tab delimited file and I want to sum up certain decimal number to the output (1.5) each time its find number instead of character to the first column and print out the results for all the rows from the first to the last.

I have example file which look like this:

It has 8 rows

```
  1st-column 2nd-Column

  a             ship
  1             name     
  b            school
  c             book
  2             blah
  e             blah
  3             ...
  9             ...
```

Now I want my script to read line by line and if it finds number sum up 1.5 and give me output just for first column like this:

```
  0
  1.5
  1.5
  1.5
  3
  3
  4.5
  6
```

my script is:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  for c in {1..8}
  do
  awk 'NR==$c { if (/^[0-9]/) sum+=1.5} END {print sum }' file
  done
```

but I don't get any output!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try to clarify further. How is a becoming 0 and then 3 times 1.5 shows up.

Comment: In the first row of the first column, the script couldn't find any number so it gives 0. then in the second row of first column it found number so it adds 1.5, in the third and forth rows it couldn't find any number so it didn't add 1.5 to it, so it became 1.5 for those two rows. then in fifth column it found number again so it added up 1.5 which became 3. in row 6th no number found still be 3. then in 7th row it found number again and added up 1.5 again and became 4.5. and the last row was not a number so it still be 4.5. does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use awk:

```
awk '{if (/^[0-9]+[[:blank:]]/) sum+=1.5} {print sum+0 }' file
```

Edited to simplify based on jaypal's answer, bound the number and work with tabs and spaces.

Comment: This compares $0 to the regex, which would match if there's a number in the second column - and since it's incompletely anchored, would also match "1a" in the first column.  I do like the "sum+0" rather than using a BEGIN block, though.

Comment: Thanks. Edited to bound number.

Answer (score 5):

The last item in your expected output appears to be incorrect. If it is, then you can do:

```
$ awk '$1~/^[[:digit:]]+$/{sum+=1.5}{print sum+0}' file
0
1.5
1.5
1.5
3
3
4.5
6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $sum = 0;
while (<DATA>) {
    my $data = (split)[0]; # 1st column
    $sum += 1.5 if $data =~ /^\d+$/;
    print "$sum\n";
}

__DATA__
a             ship
1             name     
b            school
c             book
2             blah
e             blah
3             ...
6             ...
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
perl -lane 'next unless $F[0]=~/^\d+$/; $c+=1.5; END{print $c}' file
```

Or

```
awk '$1~/^[0-9]+$/{c+=1.5}END{print c}' file
```

These only produce the final sum as your script would have done. If you want to show the numbers as they grow use:

```
perl -lane 'BEGIN{$c=0}$c+=1.5 if $F[0]=~/^\d+$/; print "$c"' file
```

Or

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=0}{if($1~/^[0-9]+$/){c+=1.5}{print c}}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're multiplying the first field by 1.5 or adding 1.5 to a sum every time there's any number in $1 and ignoring the contents of the line otherwise.  Here's both in awk, using your sample data as the contents of "file."

`$ awk '$1~/^[0-9]+$/{val=$1*1.5}{print val+0}' file
0
1.5
1.5
1.5
3
3
4.5
9`

`$ awk '$1~/^[0-9]+$/{sum+=1.5}{print sum+0}' file
0
1.5
1.5
1.5
3
3
4.5
6`

Or, here you go in ksh (or bash if you have a newer bash that can do floating point math), assuming the data is on STDIN

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
sum=0
while read a b
do
  [[ "$a" == +([0-9]) ]] && (( sum += 1.5 ))
  print $sum
done
```